# Disable animations when testing AngularJS app with protractor

Tags: angularjs, jquery-animate, protractor

I have some code in my AngularJS app which displays/hides some divs using animations like: `$(el).fadeOut()`.

How can I disable the animations when testing with protractor using: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fx.off ? Can I somehow run that small piece o code in the browser directly from protractor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it:

```
var ptor = protractor.getInstance();
ptor.get("http://localhost:9000/");
ptor.driver.executeScript("$.fx.off = true;");
```

Comment: Some time after this was posted the syntax changed. It is now browser.executeScript('$.fx.off = true'): There is also this way: http://gitelephant.cypresslab.net/angular-js/commit/82213efff23a71ca37e1a99c11ef6bc49b1af1eb which works pretty well.

Comment: @MBielski That link is dead. Can you post what was on the other end as another answer to this question?

Comment: Looks like this might be useful, but it may be specific to Angular: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584451/how-to-disable-animations-in-protractor-for-angular-js-application