# Protractor how to wait for options

Tags: protractor

I have code like this:

```js
        element(by.model("roleSelection.role")).element(by.cssContainingText('option', newRole)).click();//.then(function() {console.log('role click')})//;
```

where the options is loaded via a call to the server.

I can wait for the first element by doing this

```js
   browser.wait(function() {
return browser.isElementPresent(by.model("roleSelection.role")).then(function(present){
    return present;
});}, 8000);
```

and it seems to work. But how can I wait until the "sub-element" is clickable.
I have tried this

```js
   browser.wait(function() {
return browser.isElementPresent(by.model("roleSelection.role")).then(function(present){
    if (present) {
        var elm = element(by.model("roleSelection.role"));
        return elm.isElementPresent(by.cssContainingText('option', newRole)).then(function(subpresent) {
            return subpresent;
        });
    }
});   }, 8000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried clickable? Something along these lines

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var select = element(by.model("roleSelection.role"))
var isClickable = EC.elementToBeClickable(select);
browser.wait(isClickable,5000); //now options should have been loaded by now
```

Comment: This seems to have solved it (most of the time anyway). Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Well, try to this: https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.elementToBeClickable

But, Please keep in mind, Protractor is suitable for angular webpages and interactions, and animations. For example ng-animate. So, it is not sure to working for example jquery, or other animates.

In this way:

```
 onPrepare: function () {
    // disable animations when testing to speed things up
    var disableNgAnimate = function () {
      angular.module('disableNgAnimate', []).run(function ($animate) {
        $animate.enabled(false);
      });
    };
    browser.addMockModule('disableNgAnimate', disableNgAnimate);
  }
```

Or you can switch in script way in `browser.executeScript()`.
Please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852713/disable-animations-when-testing-angularjs-app-with-protractor). It works only jquery animations.

If you not have animate problems. Use `setTimeout()` JS function.

Comment: The page is angular but with manual bootstapping. This page is efter login, then I select role. After that the page fetches the "departments" to select from. Now when this is fetched I select "department".

Comment: I have tried expectedconditions but it didn't work, not even the simple version that works above.The message was something like "could not bind".